# new Twilio.TaskRouter.Workspace() gives WebSocket Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

So I have the following code:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Jwt\TaskRouter\WorkerCapability;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$authToken = "your_auth_token";
$workspaceSid = "WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$capability = new WorkerCapability($accountSid, $authToken, $workspaceSid);
$capability->allowFetchSubresources();
$capability->allowActivityUpdates();
$capability->allowReservationUpdates();
$token = $capability->generateToken();
// By default, tokens are good for one hour.
// Override this default timeout by specifiying a new value (in seconds).
// For example, to generate a token good for 8 hours:
$token = $capability->generateToken(28800);  // 60 * 60 * 8
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.20/taskrouter.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var workspace = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Workspace("<?= $token ?>");
</script>
```

The PHP code generates a token just fine but the JS generates the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to '...' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

Any ideas what's up with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting up a `WorkerCapability` in your JWT but are trying to use it with the SDK `Workspace` object.  I believe you need to be using a `WorkspaceCapability` token if you want to instantiate a `Workspace` object from the SDK.